# How to get Hardware Board Revision Number via SNMP

Tags: cisco-catalyst, snmp

I'm trying to get the Hardware Board Revision Number from a ~100 cisco 29xx switches, and thought that an snmpwalk might be the quickest way.

But I'm unable to find a OID for this purpose.

The closest i get is 1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1 which gives me most of the information from `show version`, but not the revision number.

Does anyone know the proper one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have a 2900 series to try this against, but give the following OID a shot.

- **Object Name:** c2900InfoBoardRevision
- **OID:** 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.87.1.1.1

Sources:

- [Cisco SNMP MIB Reference](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=c2900InfoBoardRevision&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true)
- [Cisco MIB Browser](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&step=2&mibName=CISCO-C2900-MIB) (You'll have to Ctrl+F for the ObjectName)

Comment: Jordan, you were right.  I misunderstood the question.  I deleted my answer.